# Python comtypes cancel opening of file with password

Tags: python-3.x, comtypes

I have a python script where I'm using comtypes to process ms office files. However some of the documents I need to process have passwords, causing my script to be stuck when I trigger my script as a batch as it waits input for the password prompt?

Is there an option to cancel opening the file if it the file has a password programmatically?

```
import comtypes    
word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Open(src_filename)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PasswordDocument keyword argument for that :

```
doc = word.Documents.Open(r"d:\test.docx",PasswordDocument="test")
```

whole snippet (tested with python3.6):

```
from comtypes.client import CreateObject
word = CreateObject('Word.Application')
word.visible = True
doc = word.Documents.Open(r"d:\test.docx",PasswordDocument="test")
```

Comment: Great! This would do the trick for me and enclose it to a try catch block to continue the loop of processing other files

Comment: Does the PasswordDocument keyword also apply for other office documents such as ppt and msg?